# Prikry forcing and Cohen generic

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a normal measure on $\kappa$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the standard Prikry forcing using $\mathcal{U}$. Let $\mathbb{Q} = \text{Add}(\kappa, 1)$ be Cohen forcing for adding a new subset to $\kappa$ using partial functions from $\kappa$ to $2$ of size ${<}\kappa$.

**Question:** Is there a projection from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Isn't every intermediate extension of a Prikry extension also a Prikry extension by a theorem of Gitik-Kanovei-Koepke?

Comment: Here is the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228378916_Intermediate_models_of_Prikry_generic_extensions. Also Koepke has some talk slides from a talk he gave at our seminar: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Talks/Submodels_of_Prikry_generic_extensions.pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following result of Tom Benhamou and Gitik might be related:

**Theorem.** Suppose $V$ satisfies $GCH$ and $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal. Then in a cofinality preserving generic extension, there exists a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter $U$ on $\kappa$ such that Prikry forcing with $U$ adds a Cohen subset of $\kappa$ over $V$.

See page 69 of the paper [Sets in Prikry and Magidor Generic Extensions](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~gitik/Article.pdf).

Comment: So the assumption of normality (or at least that the ultrafilter is P-point) is necessary in the theorem of Gitik, Kanovei and Koepke.

Comment: Note that the Cohen is generic over ground model, so it does not address the above result of Gitik-Kanovei-Koepke